# Entity Framework Enums and Datanotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I want to the use `enum` feature in Entity Framework 5.0 with Code First and Data Annotation and could not find any examples related to this technique. I created a table that has a column called Option type int to capture the data from my enum:

public enum Options : int
    {
        Option1 ,
        Option2 ,
        Option3 
   }

Do you have any example to use the Data Annotation for enum?

Answer (score 0):

I had some question of that kind myself.

Check my working example (2nd piece of code) here: [Code First Enum not allowed within 'Enums' class? (EF 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574053/code-first-enum-not-allowed-within-enums-class-ef-5)

Good luck!