# Code First Enum not allowed within 'Enums' class? (EF 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to do something really simple. I want to use an `Enum` as column type in my Code First solution. I am using Entity Framework 5.0 Stable Release.

Consider my `Enum`s wrapper class and Model:

```
public class Enums
{
    public enum UserType
    {
        Bronze = 0,
        Silver = 1,
        Gold = 2,
        Admin = 4
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Enums.UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

If I generate the database the column `UserType` is not generated. When I remove the '`class` wrapper' around my `Enum` like this:

```
public enum UserType
{
    Bronze = 0,
    Silver = 1,
    Gold = 2,
    Admin = 4
}
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

It **DOES** gets generated! Is my first setup such an uncommon or 'please do not' approach?

I would like to hear some suggestions that are standardized or best practice and/or explanations why my first setup doesn't work.

Comment: You could place your enums in a namespace instead of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested types (be it enums, complex types or entities) are not supported by EF.

Comment: So it seems! Thanks though. Where did you find this information? I would like to read some more about 'limitations' or 'will work in the future'...

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen anyone use a wrapper class around an `Enum` before.  Of course, it may be that I don't get around enough.  :)  I've seen catch-all files that contained lots of `enum` definitions inside of one namespace, but never a wrapper class.  I don't see that the wrapper class adds anything.

As @Pawel has said, nested types are not supported by EF.  And this sort of makes sense:  if you're instantiating the inner type but not the outer type, what's the point of the outer type?

Comment: Yes, well... I had both options in mind. Now I have a reason to go for the namespace. The advantage I thought of having it wrapped in a class was that the namespace was smaller and the `enum` itself was prefixed with 'Enums'

Comment: You could always add an extra segment to your namespace:  `namespace 321X.Enums` rather than just `namespace 321X`.

Comment: What Ann said.  What you are really looking for is a nested namespace (which is supported by EF).  Unless the enum is only used within the class (and not exposed externally), there is no need to place an enum within the class definition.